# The most efficient way to create a new instance of JS object

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to find out the most effecient way to create a new instance of an object.

When I started, I used something like this:

```
var Foo = function(a, b, c)
{
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}

Foo.prototype.func = function()
{
    // Do stuff;
}

var bar = new Foo(1, 2, 3);
bar.func();
```

Afterwards I heard it be better to skip the prototype because the new prototypes would use up unneeded memory, getting something like this:

```
var Foo = function(a, b, c)
{
    return {
        a:a,
        b:b,
        c:c,
        func:function()
        {
            // Do stuff;
        }
    }
}

var bar = Foo(1, 2, 3);
bar.func();
```

However, now I have the problem of creating the same func multiple times when invoking multiple instances of Foo... so how about...

```
var Foo = {
    a:null,
    b:null,
    c:null,
    func: function()
    {
        // Do stuff;
    }
}

function newFoo(a, b, c)
{
    var tmp = function(){};
    var obj = new tmp();
    obj.prototype = Foo;
    obj.a = a;
    obj.b = b;
    obj.c = c;

    return obj;
}

var bar = newFoo(1, 2, 3);
bar.func();
```

But now I got the prototype back...

I am looking for speed here, that is my main concern. The objects in question are not too complicated, mostly a bunch of attributes and functions. Objects can be created and destroyed in a quick pace (this is why speed is important)

Who knows that the most effecient method is for this?

Comment: Why not set up a simple test case at http://jsperf.com/ and see which is faster?

Comment: One shared (prototype) function is less memory but slower, because of walking the prototype chain. Is it memory or speed you're after?

Comment: @GGG because there might be solutions I am not aware of,

Comment: @pimvdb I'm after speed for this one.

Comment: @minitech I wish I hadn't seen that.

Comment: @minitech: Your jsPerf is testing the speed of *creating* the constructor instead of just creating objects from the constructor. You're losing the benefit of not having to create the `func` method for each object instance.

Comment: @amnotiam: You're right, sorry. Let me fix the tests.

Comment: YAY! [The prototype is fastest.](http://jsperf.com/object-creation-efficiency) @GGG

Comment: @minitech ahh, that's more like it! I think I'd make that an answer :)

Comment: http://jsperf.com/object-creation-efficiency/2

It's nearly the same speed I think. For this easy test case of course.

Comment: @minitech Thanks :) Put it up as an anwser and I'll accept it :)

Comment: @Andreas, the real life objects would be quite big. So I imagine a larger difference there :P

Comment: And the prototype is, at least that's what I think, the way to go with javascript.
Too bad `Object.create()` is not working as designed in older browsers and is slow, too. Maybe this will be fixed in a better future and we can get rid of this `new` statement no one likes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, the prototype is apparently what's fastest for creating an object. http://jsperf.com/object-creation-efficiency gives it as being 2% faster than creating a new object, at least on Google Chrome Canary.

#### Browsers where prototype is faster

- Chrome Canary 19.0.1056.0
- Firefox 10.0.2

#### Browsers where creating a new object is faster

- Chrome 17.0.963